# Safety of using \0 before the end of character arrays

Tags: c, char

I am writing a driver for an embedded system that runs a custom version of modified linux (Its a handscanner). The manufacturer supplys a custom Eclipse Juno distribution with a few libraries and examples inbound.

The output I receive from the comport comes in form of a standard character array. I am using the individual characters in the array to convey information (error ids and error codes) like this:

```
if (tmp[i] == 250])
```

Where `tmp` is a character array in form of char `tmp[500];` that is first initialized to `0` and then filled with input from the comport.

My question is:

Assuming I iterate through every piece of the array, is it safe to use `0` (as in `\0`) at any point before the end of the Array? Assuming I am:

1. Not treating it as a string (iterating through and using it like an `int` array)
2. In knowledge of what is going to be in there and what exactly this random \0 in the middle of it is supposed to mean.

The reason im asking is because I had several coworkers tell me that I should never ever ever use a character array that contains `\0` before the end, no matter the circumstances.

My code doing this currently performs as expected, but im unsure if it might cause problems later.

Rewriting it to avoid this behaviour would be a non-trivial chunk of work.

Comment: I think as long as you never use string functions (`strcpy`, `strcat`, etc) should be no problem

Comment: i think your main problem is going to be to do with things like `tmp[i] == 250`. if tmp is a char, then it's undefined whether or not it's signed or unsigned. if it's signed, then that statement can never be true as it has to be between -128 and 127

Comment: @TomTanner It is given that the char is always unsigned.

Comment: It's ok. I'd possibly use `signed char` or `unsigned char` rather than `char` as a notice that it isn't supposed to be treated as a string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using an array of `char` as an array of small integers is perfectly fine. Just be careful not to pass it to any kind of function that expects "strings".

And if you want to be more explicit about it, and also make sure that the array is using `unsigned char` you could use [`uint8_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer) instead.

Comment: I don't decide what the array is. Its expected to be a char array by the manufacturer function that I use to retrieve the data. Im unsure wether or not converting it to another type would do harm in that.

Comment: @Magisch There's no harm keeping it as a `char` array, as long as you are aware of the limitation (no string functions) and also document it for future readers/users of the code.

Comment: Alright then. Thank you for your assertion. (My coworkers usually also defer to SO as means of guidance so linking them to this will help)